# Vba code doesn't behave as it should in Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel

I just got alot of problem and can't find a solution.
I made a pretty large macro that has been used for a couple of years in Excel 2003. Now my friend upgraded to office 2010 and suddenly macros dont work as they should.

I traced one error to this line that seems to drop the decimals for a variable.
This line:

```
varHeight = ActiveSheet.Pictures("temp").Height
```

In Excel 2003 this line reads the height of the picture called "temp" and variable "varHeight" gets the value 5,25.

If I try the same in Excel 2010 variable "varHeight" gets value 5. So here the decimal is dropped. I don't understand how come this happens.

Variable varHeight is declared by this line:

```
Dim AntalMMPerPixel, IsoHöjd, varHeight As Double
```

What I do in this macro is that I build a blueprint where use diffrent pictures to build a blueprint. So I use the height of that picture to calculate where to place the rest of them.

I used a breakpoint in the code to see what value is assigned to the variable, both in Excel 2003 and Excel 2010.

Any tips or ideas an much appreciated?

Best regards

Comment: What is varHeight declared as?

Comment: You need to provide more details. As justnS asked - what type of variable is `varHeight` ? How do you know the value is different - ie. what are you doing with varHeight after getting the picture's height ?

Comment: FWIW: the ``Height`` property returns a Double.

Comment: Sorry all of you, i edited the post :)

Comment: Quick tought: Could the fact that i'm running Windows 7 English and Excel 2010 Swedish in the system where it doesnt work and the other system runs Windows XP Pro Swedish and Excel 2003 Swedish.. Could the language diffrents effect i any way?

Comment: In your Dim statement only varHeight is set to a double. The other variables are of type Variant. Is that what you intended?

Comment: The height is returned as a single. Just to be sure that you are truly receiving the integer value, try manually changing the height via code to something with a decimal and then read the height again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find any documentation on the Picture collection as you have it.  There might have been a change to it between versions, but it appears undocumented.  You can try to utilize the shape object to see if that helps at all.  It gave me correct double value in excel 2003, however, I'm unable to test on excel 2010.

```
Public Sub Test()

    MsgBox GetPictureHeight(Sheets("Sheet1"), "Picture 1")
End Sub

Public Function GetPictureHeight(wrk As Worksheet, pictureName As String) As Double
'returns the height of the named picture on the specific worksheet

    Dim pic As Shape

    Set pic = wrk.Shapes(pictureName)

    GetPictureHeight = pic.height
End Function
```

Comment: I just tried the above code and in Excel 2010 it gives the value 5.. No decimals? Isnt that strange, could they have changed something about picture.height so it doesnt use decimals anymore. Seems strange..

Comment: I just tested this with Excel 2010 US English running under Windows 7 Enterprise. For my sample picture I get the value 590.400024... It is returning decimal values.

Comment: You did?? I cant understand this? I just had a tought about that Excel 2010 is swedish version and in sweden we use "," to mark decmials and US uses "." and sens windows is english there might be something there? maybe?

Comment: My bad, i used the exact same picture and in excel 2003 it says that the height is 5.25 and in Excel 2010 it says 5.. I tried another picture in excel 2010 and then i get a value with decimals, so, decimals seems to work in excel 2010 to.. Strange though that i get diffrent height values for the same picture?